# How we share Data between 2 html pages without using local storage or cookies

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ajax

I will try the share data using local storage. but I want to that shared data visible all that web page users.

Mainly I was try to some variable upload the one html page local storage and I try to get that value another web page and I want to make condition in use that variable. But problem is I will use the local storage all details are visible only me. I want to visible that data in all users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want share data between all users, a solution on the client is the wrong approach as the users do not share the client data with each others.

So, you have to look for a solution in the backend, i.e. on your server. Either you can share the data across your users via the database or via a cache on your server (e.g redis etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data through the query parameters-

```
https://test.com/hello?name=roger&age=20
```

Please check the link for details: [Link](https://flaviocopes.com/urlsearchparams/)